# Facebook insights API PHP

Tags: php, facebook

Using the Facebook PHP SDK, how can I query the API so I can get data about a selected number of insight metrics in just one API request?

I know how to get ALL values in one go using it like this:

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$since = strtotime($today. " -1 days");             
$until = strtotime($today);

$params = array(
'since' => $since, 
'until' => $until
);

$insights = $this->facebook->api('/my-page-id/insights/', "GET", $params);
```

or to get just one metric (like page_impressions) using the above code but modifying the request to something like this:

```
$insights = $this->facebook->api('/my-page-id/insights/page_impressions', "GET", $params);
```

my question is how can I get metrics about lets say 10 different metrics (like `page_impressions`, `page_impressions_unique`, `page_fans`, etc), but leaving out everything else?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/

Comment: I have tried a few ways to use the field expansion but cannot get it to work with insights because it requires me to use syntax like /insights/page_impressions?since=etc, if I try to use /insights?fields=page_impression,page_fans,etc it just fetches everything. Got an example of a url that works with insights?

Comment: Just add `fields` as an _additional_ GET parameter to the existing ones.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesnt work with insights, I can get it to work with other requests, but doing something like https://graph.facebook.com/my-page-id/insights?fields=page_impressions,page_fans&since=1377561600&until=1377648000&access_token=my-page-access-token only gives me back every insights for the page. It just ignores the "fields" values.

Comment: OK, maybe that’s not possible for insights. You could try the [FQL insights table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights) instead – should be possible to filter for a couple of metrics using `WHERE metric IN ('foo', 'bar')` I guess.

Comment: I will have a look at FQL for this, thanks for your help so far.